# How to exclude a part of a Django template file from processing?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django template file that has a couple of **enormous** strings in it (images encoded in Base64). When I use the Django templating engine, it chokes and takes 5 minutes to render the template. Is there a way to exclude a part of a template, with something like:

```
{% ignore %}
  <img src='....'>
{% endignore %}
```

Does this exist?

Comment: Try to use {% comment %}{% endcomment %}

Comment: @DimaKudosh I thought of that but the problem is that I still want the content between the tags to be included in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`verbatim`** tag!

From django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

> **verbatim**
>
> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block
>   tag.
>
> A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides
>   with Django’s syntax. For example:
>
> ```
> {% verbatim %}
>     {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
> {% endverbatim %}
> ```